# How to fix WhatsApp Click to chat link not finding WhatsApp messenger on phones

Tags: android, ios, whatsapp

I have created a product page on an AppSheet app with a WhatsApp click to chat link. However, this link only opens the share on WhatsApp web page with correct number and pre-filled text(picture 1). When I click on send, the code can't find WhatsApp on the phone and redirecting to install WhatsApp messenger(picture 2).

Below is the link I'm using:
https://wa.me/260969XXXXX1?text=Hi,%20I%27m%20interested%20in%20this%20Descriptive%20top%20bottom.%20Product%20ID:%209cf30b16

picture 1

[image: Opens Share on WhatsApp]

picture 2

[image: Fails to find WhatsApp Messenger and redirects to install WhatsApp Messanger]

What could be the problem? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

for me using the following url works on android

```
"http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+toNumber +"&text="+text
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an exception to the phone you use. Normally if WhatsApp is installed on the phone, it needs to be opened. Please try on another device.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the link. It turns out I was using the links in AppSheet wrongly and I only need to use the external link instead.

Comment: what do you mean external link? give an example of code or the solution code please